# Which would be the advantages of a fresh new install despite a system clonning?

Tags: debian, system-installation, debian-installer

Clonned a system via `dd`, `/etc/fstab` and `mtab` files fixing, then `grub-install` on it.

Are there any advantages of doing a fresh new installation despite that procedure?

Talking in a matter of system efficiency, reading speed, CPU usage, disregarding the overwork of configuring a fresh new install.

Comment: None that I can think of. A new install will feature less logs in /var/log but other than that, there'll be no difference. Linux/Unix is not Windows and it doesn't accumulate junk you're not aware of.

Comment: Too late now but you didn't have to fiddle with `fstab` or grub with this script: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028604/bash-script-to-backkup-clone-ubuntu-to-another-partition

Comment: Woudn't it copy a partitioned system, as `/`, `usr`, `var`, `tmp`, `home` separeted partitions, @WinEunuuchs2Unix?

Comment: @Raymond83 Oops, not it's not designed to support copying 5 current partitions to 5 new partitions. I put `/` and her children in one partition and forget others have their reasons for skipping simple installations. In your case you will need to fiddle all about and could not use the script to clone the partition..